# How do I integrate the CardUI library?

Tags: android, cardslib

I've found a UI library (https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib) - how do I implement this into my project? I'm completely clueless. Do I have to use Gradle? If so, could anyone please guide me?
I'm using Eclipse as my IDE.
How do I implement this library?
I've tried to add it as a library through importing a file system and adding the external libraries through the build path.

Answer (score 1):

The author of the library has published [instructions for how to attempt to use the library from Eclipse](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/BUILD.md#reference-this-project-as-a-library-in-eclipse).

Comment: I'm still clueless, do I import the library folder as a separate project or do I import it into an existing project?

Comment: @user3422952: The term "import", when used with Eclipse, usually means a separate project.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I've rendered the project as a library, do I just reference the project to my existing project as a library by doing Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects -> Add?

Comment: @user3422952: No, you add it the same way that you [add any other Android library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject).